# How do I use an if else statement in a loop?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am trying to create an new column in a dataframe titled "Date2" which I will have to loop through previous iterations of the calculation.

The following is the logic.

```
If ID2 = Previous(ID2) then Previous(Date2) ELSE
Date1 + 60


Example:

ID2     Date 1     Date 2
1001    1/1/2019   3/2/2019
1001    1/1/2019   3/2/2019
```

In row 1 Date2 is simply Date1+60 since the previous ID2 is different.
In row 2 Date2 is simply the previous Date2 since the previous ID2 is the same as the current.

Code:

```
OrderedData$Well2BookDate <- 0 # initialize, sometimes better as just `list()`

for(i in 2:nrow(OrderedData)){
  if(OrderedData[i,1]== OrderedData[i-1, 1]){
    # Previous Well 2 Book Date
    OrderedData[i,14 ] <- OrderedData[i-1, 14] 
  } else {
    # Online Date 1 + 60 Days
    OrderedData[i, 14] <- OrderedData[i, 9] + 60
  } 
  }
```

This code works mostly except the Well 2 Book Date is being output as a number instead of a date.  Online Date 1 was already a date class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493645/r-if-else-with-for-loop perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

An option is `lag` with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(NewDate = case_when(ID2 == lag(ID2) ~ lag(Date2), TRUE ~ Date1 + 60))
```

Comment: That won't work since Date2 and NewDate you have are the same variable

Comment: @TimBatten  You haven't provided an example, so it is not clear what your Date2s are

Comment: ID2            Date 1               Date 2
1001         1/1/2019       3/2/2019
1001         2/1/2019        3/2/2019

Comment: Row 1 does Date 1 + 60 since the previous ID2 isn't the same.  In row 2 it it simply takes the previous Date 2 since the previous ID2 is the same

Comment: @TimBatten  Please edit your post and update the data.  It is difficult to copy/paste from here

Comment: @TimBatten  If you haven't created the 'Date 2', I don't understand `If ID2 = Previous(ID2) then Previous(Date2) ELSE
Date1 + 60`

Comment: row 1 of the frame will automatically do Date+60. Once it has a previous ID to compare to (starting in row 2) then the logic from the previous comment will apply